# How to Insert new records using SSIS? Can I use Exec SQL task or OLE DB Source SQL Command text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created a table called DimInternationalFunction.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DimInternationalFunction]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [DimInternationalFunction]
Go
Create Table DimInternationalFunction
(IntFunctionKey int NOT NULL identity primary key,
SubSubFunctionString char(10),
FunctionCode char(3),
SubFunctionCode char(6),
SubSubFunctionCode char(10),
SubSubFunctionName nvarchar(60),
SubFunctionName nvarchar(60), 
FunctionName nvarchar(60))
```

---

I have initially inserted records in this table in SSMS.

---

After inserting the initial records manually in SSMS, now my manager wants me to insert "new records only" using SSIS.

I have tried using this in SSMS and it worked. Either it gives me 0 records inserted or sometimes it gives me 5 records inserted as a result. My manager wants me to do this in SSIS.

I tried using this script inside the OLE DB Source under Data Access Mode: SQL Command and SQL Command text:

```
insert into DWResourceTask.dbo.DimInternationalFunction
select f.SubSubFunctionString,
f.FunctionCode,
f.SubFunctionCode,
f.SubSubFunctionCode,
f.SubSubFunctionName,
f.SubFunctionName, 
f.FunctionName
 from ODS_Function F
where FunctionViewCode = 'INT'
and not exists (select * from DWResourceTask.dbo.DimInternationalFunction I
                where (f.SubSubFunctionString=i.SubSubFunctionString
                        and f.FunctionCode=i.FunctionCode
                        and f.SubFunctionCode=i.SubFunctionCode
                        and f.SubSubFunctionCode=i.SubSubFunctionCode
                        and f.SubSubFunctionName=i.SubSubFunctionName
                        and f.SubFunctionName=i.SubFunctionName
                        and f.FunctionName=i.FunctionName)
)
```

The error message that I got after clicking preview is

```
The component reported the following warnings:

Error at Int Function [International Function Table [33]]: No column information was returned by the SQL command.


Choose OK if you want to continue with the operation.
Choose Cancel if you want to stop the operation.
```

Is there another component in SSIS that can do this? or can I just use either exec sql task component or ole db source?

I am thinking of using exec sql task connected to a data flow task, inside the data flow task I will put ole db source containing a staging table and do a delete on that or is there any other way to do it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use 'Execute SQL task' and put your code inside...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an Execute SQL task.

If you want to do it "the pure SSIS way", you could use a lookup component. Set the "rows with no matching" handler to "Redirect to no match output", and configure the target table as connection. Then use the "No Match Output" only, ignoring the "Match Output". And send the records from the "No Match Output" to the target.

In spite of its name, the "Lookup" component can be used to filter data in many cases.

But I would assume the Execute SQL task would be more efficient for large data sets, keeping all data within the database engine.